# How to get image from user in java

Tags: java, image

Is there any way that I can **input image at runtime using java**? Like we ask user to input Integer and use the function `input.nextInt()`.

Also I want to put restriction that input `image` is only of `jpeg` type ?

Comment: You can give the path to the image file as an input to your program.

Comment: Yes ask the user for the full file path including file name. Then you can use java.io.File to get a handle on it and process it as you like.

Comment: Or if you are bad one, let the user enter the binary data in base64 ;) Then you can convert this string back to the binary data of the image.

Comment: only absolute path you may pass and validate the file name using `extension` of file.

Comment: @ReneM. if user enter the binary data then how you validate the inserted raw data as a `.jpeg`

Comment: That is an other problem, you could solve by asking the user, too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static Boolean isJPEG(File filename) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        try {
            if (ins.readInt() == 0xffd8ffe0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;

            }
        } finally {
            ins.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));  
I don't get it..

Comment: DataInputStream enable you to read primitive data from a stream. It implements DataInput interface.

DataInput interface defines methods that convert primitive values from a sequence of bytes.

The BufferedInputStream class provides buffering to your input streams.

FileInputStream is a bytes stream class that’s used to read bytes from file